# WillPopScope is deprecated after flutter 3.12

Tags: flutter

When we use below code after flutter version 3.12.0 we are getting deprecated message, what to use insted of this now?

```
WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () {
            setStatusBarColor(statusBarColorPrimary,statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light);
            finish(context);
            return Future.value(true);
          },)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`WillPopScope` is deprecated after flutter `v3.12.0-1.0.pre`.

Now you can use `PopScope` as below:

```dart
return PopScope(
    canPop: true, //When false, blocks the current route from being popped.
    onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
        //do your logic here:
        setStatusBarColor(
            statusBarColorPrimary,
            statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
        );
        finish(context);
    },
    child: Scaffold(/*other child and ui etc*/),
);
```

Comment: Any idea how to send data through without having the `onPopInvoked` method executing twice?

Comment: but how can we perform asyn operations in `canPop`?

Comment: maybe this article answers your questions? https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back

Answer (score 9):

If you really need **conditional async navigation** you can do this:

```
      PopScope(
          canPop: false, // prevent back
          onPopInvoked: (_) async {
            // This can be async and you can check your condition
            final backNavigationAllowed = await something();
            if (backNavigationAllowed) {
              // Manually navigate back
              if (mounted) Navigator.of(context).pop();
            } else {
              // User is still on the same page, do whatever you want
            }
          },
          child: ...
      );
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But I must say in comparison to the `WillPopScope` this is not very idiomatic. Especially having `canPop: false` made me think the whole thing is deactivated when this is the case. There should be a note or two in the docs IMHO. Of course that's a Flutter issue, the answer is correct.

Comment: yes, who made this api change? seems terrible. I think we can all agree that canPop: false, should be an async function call that returns a Future<boolean>, not a boolean

Answer (score 1):

I would like to take a more general approach than the existing answers.

If you want to replace the return value of onWillPop you should use the canPop attribute:

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    return _myCondition;
  },
  child: ...
),
```

will be:

```
PopScope(
  canPop: _myCondition,
  child: ...
),
```

If you use the WillPopScope to handle nested Navigators you can use the NavigatorPopHandler widget.

Both and more ways to replace WillPopScope are documented here: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back#migrating-from-willpopscope-to-navigatorpophandler-for-nested-navigators

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Replace old widget from WillPopScope with PopScope new widget
check below code

/// NEW CODE

```
PopScope(
  canPop: true,
  onPopInvoked : (didPop){
   // logic
  },
)
```

Comment: In what way is your answer different from the already accepted answer? [See above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77500681/4137032)