# Flutter double press to close the application from the current window

Tags: flutter, dart

```
return WillPopScope(
      onwillPop: () async{

      },
  
  child: Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Obx(
        () => IndexedStack(
          index: logic.currentIndex.value,
          children: logic.pages,
        ),
      ),
```

but the willpopscope is depreciated as per dart 3.2.3 version.what to do?

want to close the app only after double tap the back button with the popscope widget ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WillPopScope is deprecated after flutter 3.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77500680/willpopscope-is-deprecated-after-flutter-3-12)

Answer (score 1):

Swap out the outdated WillPopScope widget for the PopScope new widget; see the code below

```
PopScope(
  canPop: false,
  onPopInvoked : (didPop){
     if(didPop) { return; }
   // Dialog will be here...
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes  **WillPopScope** is **deprecated** and you should use popScope instead.

```
   PopScope(
         canPop: true,
         onPopInvoked: (didPop) => Navigator.pop(context),
         child: child),
```

This is a new widget provided by flutter to handle pop scope. Simply add this to any child and implement onPopInvoked method it will give you a Boolean value which gives you feedback on whether it popped or not if yes then pop scope was invoked and you can handle action accordingly.

Comment: Can u pls provide the logic how to close the app when the back button is pressed twice continuously?